# Raw query to .extra() method

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am working with distance between objects, so I use haversine formaula in a raw query:

```
query = """SELECT *, (%d*acos(cos(radians(%2f))
               *cos(radians(client_address.latitude))*cos(radians(client_address.longitude)-radians(%2f))
               +sin(radians(%2f))*sin(radians(client_address.latitude))))
               AS distance FROM jobs LEFT OUTER JOIN client_address ON ( client_address.id = jobs.location_id) HAVING
               distance < %2f AND status = 1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, %d""" % (
            earth,
            float(self.latitude),
            float(self.longitude),
            float(self.latitude),
            distance,
            limit
        )
```

This query is a object method, that's why you see `self` reference. I find out that I cant do extra filters for the resulting `RawQuerySet` unless I perform this query in a `.extra()` or `.annotate()` method. I wonder if it is possible, Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `extra()` is [discouraged in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra). It would be better to use `annotate` if possible.

Comment: Have you considered this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: That's for working with GeoDjango, I am not. The query above works fine, I've spend all my day trying with RawSQL, but seems to be bugged.